# Embed an R process in a VBA macro

Tags: vba, r, embed

the title exactly -- is there a way to call an r process from an excel macro?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with r process, but this link appears to be valid for your question.

http://www.unt.edu/rss/class/splus/UsingRWithinExcel.pdf

**RExcel - Using R from within Excel**

*Overview*

The Excel addin `RExcel.xla` allows to use R from within Excel. The package additionally contains some
Excel workbooks demonstrating different techniques for using R in Excel.
There are two types of servers, forground and background. The background server ist totally hidden from the
user, all interaction with R has to be done in Excel. The foreground server allows direct access to the R GUI
command line while working in Excel. The backgound server is installed with the R(D)COM server, the
background server depends on the {R}-package rcom, which has to be installed >from CRAN.

*Usage*

There are at least **three** different ways of using R from within Excel
Scratchpad mode
Writing R Code directly in an Excel worksheet and transferring scalar, vector, and matrix variables
between R and Excel

*Macro mode*

Writing macros using VBA and the macros supplied by RExcel.xla, attaching the macros to menu
items or toolbar items

*Worksheet functions*

R can be called directly in functions in worksheet cells

*Scratchpad Mode*

The RExcel menu contains the following items:

*R Start*

Initiates a connection to R
If necessary starts an R process to be accessed >from Excel
For the details of executing code at startup see section Startup

*Close R*

When this process is running, R Start changes to Close R
Run Code
Selecting a range (only one column wide) in Excel containing valid R code and then choosing this
menu item executes the selected code

*Get*

Gets the value of an R variable into the active Excel cell or range
Possible values are scalars and matrices of numbers or strings, or dataframes.

*Put*

Puts the values of the selected Excel range into an R variable.
Possible values are scalars and matrices of numbers or strings, or dataframes.
If a dataframe is to be put, the first row of the Excel range must contain the variable names for the
dataframe.
Put for dataframes only transfers data in visible rows and columns, hidden rows and columns will not
be transferred.

*Copy Code*

Puts the content of the selected range on the Windows clipboard, assuming that it is R code, and wraps
the code in VBA procedure calls to make it ready for inclusion in VBA macros

Comment: how do they call that, Google is your friend? :-)

Comment: Google is definitely a friend.

Answer (score 10):

RExcel, a free add-in for Excel that can be downloaded from the R distribution network. RExcel seamlessly integrates the entire set of R's statistical and graphical methods into Excel.

The book [R Through Excel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441900519) offers a good entry for those just beginning with R through the familiar Microsoft Excel..

Answer (score 0):

I'm too not familiarized with R. But I found these 2 links that can be useful:

[Windows Component Services Integrating R and Excel on the COM Layer](http://www.r-project.org/conferences/DSC-2003/Proceedings/Baier.pdf)

and,

[High-Level Interface Between R and Excel](http://www.r-project.org/conferences/DSC-2003/Proceedings/BaierNeuwirth.pdf)

[]'s

Comment: I know the accepted answer is upvoted and it makes it look like doing this OK, but... Link only answers are [grounds for removal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251006/2596334). The [reasons for this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/235574) are legion. Please read ["How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): `Provide context for links`.