# Is there any easy way to make a desktop app in R that doesn't require installing R

Tags: r

I wrote a simple R program and want to share it with my office. Most people in my office are not familiar with R and I imagine it could be kind of confusing for them to install R and all the required packages.

Is there an easy way I can share an R script that can take user inputs & share output that doesn't require R installation on the user's end? I'm thinking something like Shiny, but for desktop use.

Comment: this has gotten asked fairly often over the years, and I think the answer is usually "no" ...

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-desktop-apps-with-r/ ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730350/embed-an-r-process-in-a-vba-macro  ,,,, but close vote as request for tool recommendation.

Comment: Can you try doing it via Shiny perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Your users can run R in an R jupyter notebook that you have set up in advance on some server.  Then it's not a "desktop app" per se but it's going to look like it is running in their local web browser like Firefox or Chrome etc. Sharing R code you wrote will work excellently this way.